How to set italic font in GitHub profile bio
I am trying to set italic font in my GitHub profile biography, but it doesn't work.
As you can see in this image, I tried using both * and _ , but it doesn't work. You can confirm in my GitHub account, https://github.com/brotherrabbit91
Is there any method to solve this?

It seems that GitHub profile bios have limited support for Markdown, and italics are not supported in the bio section. However, you can use emojis and basic text formatting.
For more advanced formatting like italics, you could consider updating your README file in a repository (often a special repository named after your GitHub username for your profile). Here, Markdown syntax will work perfectly.
You can refer below document.
Github docs for changing profile

Thanks for response, one more thing, Can I insert line break in github bio?

Yes, you can not by normal method because it removes all space but I found one trick. What to do is open your github account in phone go to bio secrtion then copy first space between double quotes like this "  " now remove these whole quotes and then paste it till you do go to next line. And voila! you got a new line.
